# White Border Showing Up when No border Set

Tags: html, css

I have a strange 1px white line showing up on my index page.  I've searched through code and I cannot seem to find it anywhere.

You can see it here http://talkyoudown.net/ - at the bottom right before the text starts.  I could post the CSS source but that would take up too much space here.

If you look into the source you can see that it is in the body class (I think) but I do not have any borders set in the CSS.

Comment: you don't have any borders, but you do have a background image, which just happens to be white and 1px hight, and set to repeat horizontally, so it'll draw a line.

Comment: It's fine to close as too localized.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of the

```
.body{
    background: "url("../images/bg-content.png") repeat-x scroll left top transparent";
}
```

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you since you found the culprit.

Comment: +1: this is where the problem lies. I guess the downvote might have been because you didn't explain *why* or what to do about it.

Answer (score 2):

its your background image, specifically the fact you are repeating only on the x-axis. if you set background like this on `div.body`:

```
div.body {
    background: url(../images/bg-content.png) repeat left top;
}
```

it shows the full thing, because it repeats on both x and y axes. If you really want this to have a background of white, that'll fill it. Otherwise ... why the background at all?

Comment: actually, if you set it like that, it renders a stripy background. Not sure if that's intended, but it's harder to read. To be honest, there's unlikely to be any need for an image here at all; a plain colour should do the trick if a background is needed at all.

Comment: agreed, thats y i said if thats what u really wanted. ill mod my answer to say 'its the repeat-x specifically, as there is no repeating on the y.